# Understanding arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I was reading a book on java and under "Arrays" this example was given.

```
public class Deck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
        String[] rank = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };

        // avoid hardwired constants
        int SUITS = suit.length;
        int RANKS = rank.length;
        int N = SUITS * RANKS;

        // initialize deck
        String[] deck = new String[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < RANKS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SUITS; j++) {
                deck[SUITS*i + j] = rank[i] + " of " + suit[j];
            }
        }

        // shuffles our deck of cards
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (N-i));
            String t = deck[r];
            deck[r] = deck[i];
            deck[i] = t;
        }

        // print shuffled deck
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println(deck[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

I want to know why " **int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (N-i));**  " was used to shuffle the deck? Please explain what is done with this line and also why this line was explicitly  used.(The logic as to why this was used)

Comment: It's the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm.

Comment: `int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (N-i))` generates the random number between i to N

Comment: It is used to rearrange the order of the cards (array elements of array deck) in a random manner. You can look up Math.random in the javadoc.

Answer (score 5):

`Math.random()` returns a random `double` between 0.0 and 1.0, when this number is multiplied by `N-i` we receive a number (double) in the range of the difference between these two numbers:  `[0,N-i]`

By adding `i` we "shift" the range from `[0,N-i]` to `[i,N]` and since it's a double, we cast to `int` in order to receive an integer.

Comment: And after all @alfasin said, is used the interchange sort algorithm to change the current card with the random one.